# Scrolling on Googlemaps cause jerks and not working smoothly

Tags: ios, google-maps, smooth-scrolling

I am using google map in my iPhone app. When I scroll the map using single finger, it does not scroll smoothly and causing jerks, Actually, whenever I scroll the map, it takes the address and show on the top of the map in a textField. 
But when I scroll too quickly, then it does not scroll smoothly.
Please any help, I have this problem for about 2 days.

Thanks in advance...!

This is my code for updating address on the textfield on the top of the map.

`code`

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false",[strForLatitude floatValue], [strForLongitude floatValue], [strForLatitude floatValue], [strForLongitude floatValue]];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                     options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error: nil];

NSDictionary *getRoutes = [JSON valueForKey:@"routes"];
NSDictionary *getLegs = [getRoutes valueForKey:@"legs"];
NSArray *getAddress = [getLegs valueForKey:@"end_address"];
if (getAddress.count!=0)
{
    NSArray* str = [getAddress objectAtIndex:0];
    if(str.count > 0){
        NSString* address = [[getAddress objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
        //fix crash...
        if(![address isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
            if ([[[getAddress objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"338, Nigeria"]) {
                   self.txtAddress.text=@"";
            }
            else
                self.txtAddress.text=[[getAddress objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code of updating the textField

Comment: @a4arpan, I have added the code.